# serde.rsで構造体をmsgpackの辞書としてシリアライズするには？

Tags: rust, msgpack

Rustにおいて、自分の定義した構造体

```
struct MyStruct {
  a: i32,
  b: f64,
}
```

をmsgpackの辞書として保存するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

`serde_derive`を用いて以下のようにした場合、Listとして保存されてしまいます：

```
extern crate rmp_serde;
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct A {
    a: i32,
    b: f64,
}

fn main() {
    let f = ::std::fs::File::create("test.msg").ok().unwrap();
    let mut buf = ::std::io::BufWriter::new(f);
    let mut enc = ::rmp_serde::Serializer::new(&mut buf);
    let val = A { a: 12, b: 1.2 };
    val.serialize(&mut enc).unwrap();
}
```

この`test.msg`を[msgpack-cli](https://github.com/jakm/msgpack-cli)で表示すると

```
% msgpack-cli decode test.msg
[12,1.2]
```

のようにリストで保存されていることがわかります。
これを`{a: 12, b: 1.2}`のような辞書形式で保存するには上記のRustコードをどのように変更すればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rmp_serde::Serializer` は [`Serializer::with`](https://docs.rs/rmp-serde/0.13.5/rmp_serde/encode/struct.Serializer.html#method.with) というコンストラクタを用意しており、第2引数に渡す型に応じて構造体のシリアライズ方式を変更できます。

```
use rmp::Marker;
use rmp::encode::{write_map_len, write_str, ValueWriteError};
use rmp_serde::encode::VariantWriter;
use std::io::Write;

pub struct StructMapWriter;

impl VariantWriter for StructMapWriter {
    fn write_struct_len<W>(&self, wr: &mut W, len: u32) -> Result<Marker, ValueWriteError>
    where W: Write
    {
        write_map_len(wr, len)  // write_array_len -> write_map_len
    }

    fn write_field_name<W>(&self, wr: &mut W, key: &str) -> Result<(), ValueWriteError>
    where W: Write
    {
        write_str(w, key) // OK(()) -> write_str
    }
}

fn main() {
    // ... omit
    let mut enc = Serializer::with(&mut buf, StructMapWriter);
    // ...
}
```

※デフォルトで使用される `StructArrayWriter` は[ここ](https://github.com/3Hren/msgpack-rust/blob/master/rmp-serde/src/encode.rs#L76-L93)で定義されています。

Comment: 同様の`StructMapWriter`が以下のPRでマージされました　https://github.com/3Hren/msgpack-rust/pull/140

Answer (score 0):

rmp_serdeのドキュメントを読む限り、リストとして保存する仕様なようなのでrmp_serdeを使ってmapとして保存するのは難しいでしょう。
別のクレートを使うか自分でmapとして保存するシリアライザを書くことになりそうです。
調べたところ[corepack](https://crates.io/crates/corepack)というライブラリが[structをmapとしてシリアライズ](https://docs.rs/corepack/0.2.1/src/corepack/ser.rs.html#322)しているようだったのでそれを使うか、そのコードを参考に自作することになるかと思います。（コード例を示してませんがこれで回答になるでしょうか。